# How are transactions used when I mix EJBs and CDI beans?

Tags: java, cdi, java-ee-6

I'm working on a JEE application that only uses EJBs at the moment. The application processes messages and stores some things in the database and/or possibly sends messages to other applications (pretty straightforward I guess).

I have some filtering business logic that determines whether or not the data should be stored in a database. Something like this (simplified):

```
@MessageDriven(...)
public class MessageListener {
    private FilterProvider filter = new FilterProvider();

    @EJB private SomeDao dao;

    public void handleMessage(SomeMessage message) {
        if(filter.allows(message)) {
            dao.store(message);
        } else {
            // Ignore, not relevant
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class SomeDao {
    public store(SomeMessage message) {
        // Create the right entities and store in the db
    }
}

public class FilterProvider {
    public boolean allows(SomeMessage message) {
        return message.getAllowed() == true;
    }
}
```

Currently I'm investigating if I can use CDI to inject the FilterProvider and I've put together these modifications:

```
@MessageDriven(...)
public class MessageListener {
    @Inject
    private FilterProvider filter; // <-- Added annotation here and removed constructor call.

    @EJB private SomeDao dao;

    public void handleMessage(SomeMessage message) {
        if(filter.allows(message)) {
            dao.store(message);
        } else {
            // Ignore, not relevant
        }
    }
}

@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class SomeDao {
    public store(SomeMessage message) {
        // Create the right entities and store in the db
    }
}

@Default // <-- Added annotation here
public class FilterProvider {
    public boolean allows(SomeMessage message) {
        return message.getAllowed() == true;
    }
}
```

My first question: What is the impact on the transactions by these changes?

My second question: What kind of risks/pitfalls am I introducing by this type of setup?

Comment: In my opinion if your app is with EJB you shouldn't use CDI beans. Can't you do it with EJB ?

Comment: I can, with minimal changes I think. But the transition from a POJO to a full EJB seems a bit excessive if I look at the logic that is implemented by the filter. But I hope my two questions at the end make it clear that I'm not entirely sure that this is true. Additionally I read http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/cdi_with_or_without_ejb, which seems to be in favor of mixing EJBs and CDI beans.

Comment: CDI was designed to be operational with EJB. There is absolutely no effect on the transaction boundaries, and for lightweight logic, which requires no transaction boundaries, go for CDI beans. If within an EJB transaction context, the cdi bean will simply be invoked within the same transaction context

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was what I kind of hoped to hear.

Comment: @maress great, please then post it as an answer to make it clear for future readers. Additionally OP will be able to accept it :)